# WebMethod in my webservice should return a dataset and yet returns an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web, data-binding

[image: Screenshots Of The Code]

```
    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet GetPopularFlavors()
    {            
        return Helper.PopularItems();
    }

    localhost.Statistics s = new localhost.Statistics();
    topItems.DataSource = s.GetPopularFlavors();
```

And just for the record, im kind of new at this so im really sorry if im doing something that is obviously wrong...

Comment: Is `GetPopularFlavors` a method of the `Statistics`-class?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes

Comment: Did you rebuild your project? Maybe there´s some previois version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Web services by default return json ("stringed" objects). They can return XML too, if specified. A DataSet is complex and should be broken down into tables perhaps, or something smaller that can be easily retrieved and worked with by *any system*.

[Scott Hanselman's rant.](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

You might get away with adding the Serializable attribute to your class (? not sure), or serializing the DataSet inside the method before returning it.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass...
```

Use JSON.NET (a helper library) to do the work, then return the result.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbl);
```

It might be best to create a simpler object first and return that.

So, I think you're getting an array because the web service *has to* convert the object into something it can return via http, and it can't return a native .NET object, like a DataSet or DataTable, without converting it first.