# Return JSON instead of XML from web service using Ajax while 'contentType' is 'false'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I made an AJAX call to send an image file to one of my web service (.asmx) methods. Everything's okay, but the problem is that the web service returns XML instead of JSON because I HAVE TO set `'contentType'` to '`false'`, otherwise file can't be sent. (If I set `contentType` to `application/json; charset=utf-8`, it returns JSON but I can't do that because I'm sending a file.)

This is my JavaScript:

```
function setAvatar(imageFile, successCallback) {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("UploadedAvatar", imageFile);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Services/UserService.asmx/SetAvatar",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
        alert(result.d.IsSuccessful);
        if (typeof successCallback === 'function')
            successCallback(result);
    }
});
```

And the web service method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Result SetAvatar()
{
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedAvatar"];
    Image avatar = Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream, true, true);
    avatar = new Bitmap(avatar, new Size(150, 150));
    avatar.Save(Path.Combine(path, $"Avatar-Small.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    return new Result(true, Messages.AvatarSavedSuccessfully);
}
```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961146/webmethod-in-my-webservice-should-return-a-dataset-and-yet-returns-an-array/49961604#49961604). You're trying to return an object but it must be serialized first. You will probably be able to remove contentType after that and go with the default setting.

Comment: @wazz That didn't help me

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360139/asp-net-core-return-json-with-status-code, make sure you have `options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;`, so that the return type is based on the `Accept` header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After beating my head against the wall for many days, I finally figured out the solution which belongs to [Ajay, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11527543/7734384).

While nothing else has helped me, I used this and it worked perfectly:

1. Change the return type of your method to `void`.
2. And then instead of writing the `return` statement in your method, you need to do this to return a value:

   ```
   Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
   Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new YourData()));
   ```
3. After that you can easily get the result using the `success` event of the Ajax call:

   ```
   success: function (result) {
       alert(result.Property); // Note: Don't use result.d here
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Set the `Accept` header when making the request to expect JSON

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Services/UserService.asmx/SetAvatar",
    headers: { //SET ACCEPT HEADER
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    },  
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
        alert(result.d.IsSuccessful);
        if (typeof successCallback === 'function')
            successCallback(result);
    }
});
```

On the server side, using `Json.Net` you can serialize the result

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SetAvatar() {
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedAvatar"];
    Image avatar = Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream, true, true);
    avatar = new Bitmap(avatar, new Size(150, 150));
    avatar.Save(Path.Combine(path, $"Avatar-Small.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    var result = new Result(true, Messages.AvatarSavedSuccessfully);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

This should allow the response to be in the desired type

Comment: When I add this code, I get ajax error because the result of service method is not JSON

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi what does the result currently look like

Comment: the result is still an XML Document :(

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi even with the latest suggestion on server? Show a snippet of the result. is it XML wrapping JSON?

Comment: The second suggestion returns XML too. :( I'll put an instance in question today

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your `.NET` code and add `options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true`

```
services
    .AddMvc(options => {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    })
    //support application/xml
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
    //support application/json
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        // Force Camel Case to JSON
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```

The `dataType: 'json'` will automatically add the `Accept` header as below

```
"accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
```

If you specifically want just `application/json`, then you need to add below to your ajax options

```
headers: {
  Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
```

Comment: Where should I put that code? In other words, what is 'services' variable?

Comment: See this thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Any feedback on this?